# Android.content.context vs Sqlite

Tags: android

I am a little confused as to how values should be stored in an Android application. I noticed that I can store these values using Android.content.context and these values will persist after the application is exited or I this can be done using Sqlite.

1. Am I incorrect in my understanding?
2. What is the different?
3. Which one should be used? Best practices?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're referring to accessing SharedPreferences via Context.getSharedPreferrences?

SharedPreferences is best for storing application settings.   It gets written to an XML file you can examine under /data/data/com.myname.myapp/files .   It's okay to store other data here if it is fairly simple.

Sqlite is best when you have lots of data to store.   SQL is very good for manipulating and querying large amounts of data efficiently.